# Redux possibibilty to dispatch an action on server side

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm beginner with redux and create universal react redux application.

Is this any option to dispatch async action on server side like `store.dispatch(actions.getOutput())` on server side.

getOutput is an **asynchronous** action which fetch some api on call and change the state on redux.

I Know to dispatch it on client side with redux-thunk middleware but not understanding the process on server side

```
let context = {},
    status = 200;

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    ...reducers
});

const store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, promise)
    )
);



    const preloadedStore = store.getState()
    store.dispatch(actions.getStories());
    const finalState = store.getState();


    const ctx = ReactDomServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
            <App/>
        </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
    ),
    reactHelmet = ReactHelmet.renderStatic();

    if(context.url){
        return res.redirect(302, context.url);
    }

    if(context.status === 404){
        status = 404;
    }

    let page = renderOutput(ctx, finalState, reactHelmet);
    res.status(status).send(page);
```

Comment: You can try [redux-catch-promise](https://github.com/DenisIzmaylov/redux-catch-promise) but it looks awfully complicated though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs of redux-thunk, if you define your action like this:

```
function makeASandwichWithSecretSauce(forPerson) {

  // Invert control!
  // Return a function that accepts `dispatch` so we can dispatch later.
  // Thunk middleware knows how to turn thunk async actions into actions.

  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchSecretSauce().then(
      sauce => dispatch(makeASandwich(forPerson, sauce)),
      error => dispatch(apologize('The Sandwich Shop', forPerson, error))
    );
  };
}
```

you can then use it like this

```
store.dispatch(
  makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My wife')
).then(() => {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

Which means, on the server side you can do

```
store.dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce("My wife")).then(() => {

  const ctx = ReactDomServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  const reactHelmet = ReactHelmet.renderStatic();

  const page = renderOutput(ctx, finalState, reactHelmet);

  res.status(status).send(page);
});
```

Comment: Why not? it should set the state on server, you then have to transfer this state to the client

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log(store.getState())` inside the callback

Comment: it prints empty initial state. it would not update any state.

Comment: i would assume here the problem is with your reducer! can you share code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145569/discussion-between-anurag-jain-and-faris).